# Display notification to everyone viewing website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications

Im working on a website and I am not sure how to go about a feature I want to implement.

I have some user interactions and when they do something I want to display a message on the website (like a toast in android) to anyone who is currently viewing the website.

Im not sure where to start with this....Ive tried searching for something but havent been able to find anything that is what I want...any help pointing me in the direction as to what I should be looking into would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

On sites where you want to show notification use ajax call every second for example, which check if there is some notification to show, if so then write notification using javascript to the page